# writing test in modernizr for checking support of overflow-y:auto in browser

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

i was trying out Modernizr and was trying to write a test in it to check if a css property is supported in the browser.
Here i was writing for 'overflow-y:auto'

```
Modernizr.addTest('overflowauto', function(){
    var bool = false;
    var testProp = "overflow-y";
    var testVal = "auto";
    var styles = Modernizr._prefixes.join(testProp + ":" + testVal + "; ");
    var ret = true;
    ret =  Modernizr.testStyles('#modernizr { '+styles+' }', function(elem, rule){
        for(var i = 0; i < Modernizr._prefixes.length; i++) {
            bool = (window.getComputedStyle ?
                    getComputedStyle(elem, null) :
                    elem.currentStyle)[Modernizr._prefixes[i] + testProp] == testVal;

            if(bool) break;
        }

        return bool;

    });
    return ret;
});
```

If supported this should set   **Modernizr.overflowauto** to true.

But the thing is, this is always returning true. :(

even in android < 3 where overflow-y:auto is not supported, its returning true.
pls tell me what im doing wrong or how to achieve what im trying. pls help.